# Swift property only being set correctly when a didSet is present (can be empty)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a class, `Tweet`, with a `UInt` property named `id` which, when set in an initialiser, is only being set to the value I am setting it to *if* there is a `didSet` method present. What's even more confusing is that the `didSet` can be empty and it still works.

This is a simplified version of the class:

```swift
class Tweet: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var id: UInt = 0 {
        didSet {

        }
    }

    init() {

    }

    init(id: UInt) {
        self.id = id
    }

    convenience init(from json: JSON) {
        self.init()

        if let id = json["id_str"].string {
            self.id = UInt(id) ?? 0
        }
    }
}
```

For example, in the convenience init, `UInt(id)` could be `1197998964525731840`. If the `didSet` is there, as above, when used later in a SwiftUI view the value will be `1197998964525731840`. If the `didSet` isn't there, the value will *always* be `10749289280`, no matter what the original value was, until you relaunch the app.

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Birdsong), and as far as I can discern, the files relevent to this issue are [Tweet.swift](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Birdsong/blob/master/Birdsong/Model/Tweet.swift) and [TweetView.swift](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Birdsong/blob/master/Birdsong/View/TweetView.swift). Comment/uncomment [lines 15-19](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Birdsong/blob/aab021a5d26aa2c3ceadd9e7d80c8b716b525ca8/Birdsong/Model/Tweet.swift#L15-L19) and then run the app, input a search term in the text field, press go and scroll down to tap on the link button in the bottom-right corner of each Tweet (the URL and `id` are printed in the console).

Comment: I downloaded your project and tested it, both situations (with/without `didSet`). It doesn't seem to make any difference for me. I set a breakpoint at `Tweet.swift:49`. at this point `id` is set. When I step over (next line), `self.id` is the same as `id`. So, for me it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I don't know on what device you run this (and I'm guessing there's no iOS 13 (you use SwiftUI) device that's 32 bits), but `4294967295` is the max for UInt32, while your ids are higher. But like I said, this is probably not the problem.

Comment: Your implementation of `Identifiable` doesn't make sense - `id` should be a stable identifier - It is typically `let` not a `var` and therefore not `@Published` since it can't change.  It should also be unique, so assigning a default value of 0 isn't a great option either.   Your convenience `init` should probably be failable

Comment: @JeroenJK I'm running it on an iPhone 11 Pro Max and on iOS 13.3.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that I was using the `id` both to store the individual Tweet ID and for the Identifiable protocol is what seems to have caused the error.

```swift
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var identifier: UInt = 0
```

The above changes fixed it.